# What is address 0xbaddc0dedeadbead "Bad decode dead bead"

Tags: c++, memory, linker, osx-yosemite, crash-reports

I've had bugs on trying to dereference pointers in some class members pointing to address 0xbaddc0dedeadbead, which is obviously not a random value but a message "Bad decode dead bead", but from whom? 
Knowing this could help fixing these bugs; is it the C++ compiler (llvm), the linker, the loader, or some or other MacOS service that can produce this address? (I'm on MacOS 10.10). Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting a watchpoint showed that in my case it was freeing the heap (via destructor) that overwrote the free'd object with that value.

Answer (score 5):

Many `c++` compilers initialize your pointers with this value if you don't initialize them manually in debug mode to simplify search for non-initialized pointers dereference bugs.